# How to test an Machine Learning or statistic NLP algorithm implementation pack?

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on testing several Machine Learning algorithm implementations, checking whether they can work as efficient as described in the papers and making sure they could offer a great power to our statistic NLP (Natural Language Processing) platform.

Could u guys show me some methods for testing an algorithm implementation? 
1)What aspects? 
2)How? 
3)Do I have to follow some basic steps? 
4)Do I have to consider diversity specific situations when using different programming languages? 
5)Do I have to understand the algorithm? I mean, does it offer any help if I really know what the algorithm is and how it works?

Basically, we r using C or C++ to implement the algorithm and our working env is Linux/Unix. Our testing methods only focus on black box testing and testing input/output of functions. I am eager to improve them but I dont have any better idea now...

Great Thx!! LOL

Answer (score 2):

For many machine learning and statistical classification tasks, the standard metric for measuring quality is [Precision and Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).  Most published algorithms will make some kind of claim about these metrics, or you could implement them and run these tests yourself.  This should provide a good indicative measure of the quality you can expect.

When you talk about efficiency of an algorithm, this is usually some statement about the time or space performance of an algorithm in terms of the size or complexity of its input (often expressed in [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).  Most published algorithms will report an upper bound on the time and space characteristics of the algorithm.  You can use that as a comparative indicator, although you need to know a little bit about computational complexity in order to make sure you're not fooling yourself.  You could also possibly derive this information from manual inspection of program code, but it's probably not necessary, because this information is almost always published along with the algorithm.

Finally, understanding the algorithm is always a good idea.  It makes it easier to know what you need to do as a user of that algorithm to ensure you're getting the best possible results (and indeed to know whether the results you are getting are sensible or not), and it will allow you to apply quality measures such as those I suggested in the first paragraph of this answer.